# can you have another column default to a word when one column has a certain letter?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I receive spreadsheets that need profiles deleted but they seem to always forget one of the important things.  In the action column they are to list X and then in Column G they are to list the word DELETE.  I need to know if it is possible that when they put an X in the action column that the word DELETE will appear in column G automatically?

Comment: One option is using a formula in column G. Another option is using VBA - Worksheet_Change event.

Answer (score 1):

In this table version, a formula could look like this:

```
Column D formula: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("x",[@Flag])),"DELETE","")
```

If an "x" is found in column C (flag column), then the word "delete" is written out in column D. Else, it's left blank. The advantages of converting your data to a table is that the formula will automatically drag down when new rows are added.

[image]

If you don't have a table, then your formula would simply look like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("x",C2)),"DELETE","")
```

But then you need to remember to drag it down far enough to capture new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(A1="X","Delete","")
```

[image]